# Email list filter

Tags: php, javascript

I'm not even sure how to ask the question or even how to search for it.
I've browsed around and what i've got was some really hardcore regex

Basically, I have this textarea where I can input my list of emails like how google does it. Filter should be able to just ignore anything within a double quote and only picks up the email within < >

example: `"test" <test@test.com>,"test2" <test2@test.com>,"test3" <test@test3.com>`

I'm able to split up the emails by picking up the commas but not familiar with the < >

can anyone assist me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quickie version:

```
var textAreaVal = '"test" <test@test.com>,"test2" <test2@test.com>,"test3" <test@test3.com>';
// Better hope you don't have any "Smith, Bob"-type bits if you do it this way...
var textAreaLines = textAreaVal.split(",");
// Gonna assume you have jQuery here 'cause raw JS loops annoy me ;-)
// (if not you can hopefully still get the idea)
var emails = [];
$$.each(textAreaLines, function(index, value) {
  var email = /<(.*?)>/.exec(value)[1];
  if (email) emails.push(email);
});
// emails =  ["test@test.com", "test2@test.com", "test@test3.com"]
```

The key is this line:

```
 var email = /<(.*?)>/.exec(value)[1];
```

which essentially says:

```
 var email =
 // set email to

 /<(.*?)>/
// define a regex that matches the minimal amount possible ("?")
// of any character (".") between a "<" and a ">"

 .exec(value)
 // run that regex against value (ie. a line of input)

 [1];
 // and use only the first matched group ([1])
```

You'll probably want to do a slightly more complex regex to account for any crazy input, ensure that there's a "@", or for people who just do ",bob@smith.com," (without the brackets), but hopefully you get the idea.